# general-purpose tag

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

[general-purpose](/questions/tagged/general-purpose) seems fairly useless. Can we get rid of it? Used on 62 questions, 6 of which have it as the only tag (most of which are already closed, or probably should be.)

Comment: After encountering a couple of these questions over the last few days, I was just about to suggest the same thing.  Good riddance.

Answer (score 2):

Agreed, it is now burninated.

[image: tag burninated]